# Worklight 6.2 migration tool connection

Tags: oracle, migration, ibm-mobilefirst, upgrade

I am working to upgrade Worklight from 5.0.6.2 to 6.2
And am now doing the database upgrade thing.

I am stuck when trying to run migration tool
as following error is shown

```
"fwlse3401e Failed to connect to source database"
```

It's a local dev oracle express 11g

with service name: xe

schema to be used: CCC

The following is the command i tried.

```
java -classpath ojdbc6.jar -cp worklight-ant-deployer.jar com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.MigrationTool \
  -p /CCC \
  -sourceurl jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.*:1521/xe  \
  -sourceschema CCC \
  -sourcedriver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver \
  -sourceuser CCC \
  -sourcepassword * \
  -targeturl jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.*:1521/xe \
  -targetschema CCC \
  -targetdriver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver \
  -targetuser CCC \
  -targetpassword *
```

Should i use both -sourceschema and -sourceuser or is that i misplaced/mis-imported jdbc driver?

Btw, after reading the guide, 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_addl_info_manual_db_update.html

for the  -p param, should it be idential to context root or what is it for?

Comment: Leslie, why are you reading the 7.0 migration guide if you are trying to migrate to 6.2. Also, why migrate to 6.2 when there is 7.0?

Comment: Hi Idan, i pasted the wrong link, the one i followed is for 6.2. But I am still stuck. It's the scope we signed with our client.

Comment: Have you created the administration database first ? The migration tool migrates the administration data from the Worklight database to the new Administration database in 6.2. But that database needs to be initialized. See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr_upgrading_wl_runtime_install_wladmin.html which should be run prior upgrading the databases.

Comment: Thank you Vidal, we created schema for wladmin tables. i have created a new thread for another problem running the migration tool, may you please go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364428/worklight-6-2-migration-tool-error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed multiple -classpath / -cp options to java. In this case the last one overrides the previous ones. To start java with multiple jars in the classpath, you need to pass one -classpath / -cp option, with jars separated by a colon on Unix or a semicolon on Windows:

`java -cp ojdbc6.jar:worklight-ant-deployer.jar ...` (Unix)

`java -cp ojdbc6.jar;worklight-ant-deployer.jar ...` (Windows)

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC URL syntax is incorrect. Oracle supports [two syntaxes for a JDBC URL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm#BEIJFHHB):

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:SID`

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:1521/servicename`

"xe" typically is a SID, therefore you need the first syntax.