# Worklight 6.2 migration tool error

Tags: oracle, migration, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on migrating data from WL 5.0.6.2 to 6.2. While doing that I encountered problems running data migration tool.

Background:
Approach:
    we export the WRKLGHT table from 5062 DB to an intermediate DB for data migration so the running DB is not affected.

```
DBs:
   1. schema: proj
     its storing 5062 runtime data, upgrade-worklight-506-60-oracle.sql, upgrade-worklight-60-61-oracle.sql upgrade sql are executed.
   2. schema: proj6
     its blank DB at first, "create-worklightadmin-oracle.sql"  is executed to prepare WLADMIN tables.

WL Project existing:
    1. wlProj 
        its the app running on 5062 WL server
    2. wlProj6
        its the target project running on 6.2 WL, and data will be migrated to be used by this project

Steps:
1. recreate proj6 schema
    1.1 SQLPlus -> connect as SYSTEM -> "drop user proj6 cascade"
    1.2. -> "create user proj6 identified by {password}" -> "grant all privileges to proj6"

2. execute "create-worklightadmin-oracle.sql" on proj6 schema
     2.1 SQLDeveloper -> connect as user proj6
     2.2 run @"{ WL server install dir}/databases/create-worklightadmin-oracle.sql";
     2.3 commit

3. Open cmd and run the following command
    java -cp ojdbc6.jar;worklight-ant-deployer.jar com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.MigrationTool -p /wlProj   -sourceurl jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.0.**:1521/xe   -sourcedriver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver   -sourceuser proj   -sourcepassword ***  -targeturl jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.0.***:1521/xe   -targetdriver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver   -targetuser proj6   -targetpassword *** 2>out.txt
```

'migrating wlProj-{ios,android}' & 'migrating access data record for wlProj-.....' are shown in cmd.

And in `out.txt`, the following error is shown.

```
15  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [main] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
15  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [main] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary".
com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.exceptions.MigrationException: FWLSE3406E: The applications migration failed with error The field "description" of instance "ApplicationEntity[id=51, name=wlProj, displayName=, description=null, thumbnail=null, platformVersion=null]" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal..
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.MigrationTool.run(MigrationTool.java:195)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.MigrationTool.main(MigrationTool.java:128)
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The field "description" of instance "ApplicationEntity[id=51, name=wlProj, displayName=, description=null, thumbnail=null, platformVersion=null]" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:540)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:478)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2829)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:39)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:960)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1967)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1927)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1845)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1369)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:877)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:512)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.ApplicationMigration.migrateApplication(ApplicationMigration.java:138)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.ApplicationMigration.migrate(ApplicationMigration.java:63)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.AbstractMigration.run(AbstractMigration.java:66)
    at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration62.MigrationTool.run(MigrationTool.java:183)
    ... 1 more
ERROR 20 : FWLSE3406E: The applications migration failed with error The field "description" of instance "ApplicationEntity[id=51, name=wlProj, displayName=, description=null, thumbnail=null, platformVersion=null]" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal..
```

Answer (score 0):

This is recorded as IBM PMR #77138,999,738, and was identified as a defect that is currently being worked on.
There is no local fix to do other than wait for a fix via the support ticket.