# Worklight 6.1 to Mobilefirst 7.1 database migration issue

Tags: oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, server-configuration

I have an application running on worklight 6.1, now I want to migrate it on mobilefirst 7.1. For that I am using server configuration tool for database upgrade.

I have created a configuration. When I am trying to create a runtime using old database (oracle 11g) it gives me message your database will upgrade (That's my end goal). But while doing so it is getting fail with this error :

```
com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration.exceptions.MigrationException: FWLSE3406E: The applications migration failed with error The field "description" of instance "ApplicationEntity[id=851, name=APPName, displayName=, description=, thumbnail=null, platformVersion=, projects=[ Contextroot ]]" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal..
[configuredatabase]     at com.ibm.worklight.config.dbmigration.MigrationTool.run(MigrationTool.java:248)
[configuredatabase]     at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.runAppropriateScriptsWorklight_61_Current(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1383)
[configuredatabase]     at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.runAppropriateScriptsWorklight(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1317)
[configuredatabase]     at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.runAppropriateScripts(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1202)
[configuredatabase]     at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.configureDatabases(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:1153)
[configuredatabase]     at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.database.ConfigureDatabaseTask.execute(ConfigureDatabaseTask.java:290)
[configuredatabase]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[configuredatabase]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
[configuredatabase]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
[configuredatabase]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
```

Is this the issue with data within db tabels or a worklight issue?

Similar link on stackoverflow :
[Worklight 6.2 migration tool error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364428/worklight-6-2-migration-tool-error)

Answer (score 0):

The issue does seem to be similar in nature to the reported issue in: [Worklight 6.2 migration tool error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364428/worklight-6-2-migration-tool-error)

There may be a defect in the migration script. The suggestion is to open a PMR as there is no local fix for this.